# change image source while keeping dimensions

Tags: javascript, image

I want to chage src attribute of an image

```
$('.bact').attr('src', '00.jpg');
```

`00.jpg` has different dimensions compared to previous.

Is there a way to change the `src`, but keep original img width and height.

If `00.jpg` is smaller than original it should be streched (loss of quality doesn't matter).

If it is bigger - it should be clipped or whatever but the goal is to fill the original rectangle.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the height and width of the original image using jquery's [.width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [.height](http://api.jquery.com/height/). Then you add those height and width css properties to the `<img />` tag and change the src of it.

The second image will have the same dimensions as the previous image. For example:

```js
setTimeout(changeImage, 3000);

function changeImage() {
  let $image = $(".bact");
  let width = $image.width();
  let height = $image.height();
  console.log(`original width: ${width} height: ${height}`);
  $image.css({"height": height, "width": width});
  $image.attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Mausoleum_Ishrathona06.JPG/320px-Mausoleum_Ishrathona06.JPG");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="bact" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Mute_swans_%28Cygnus_olor%29_and_cygnets.jpg/640px-Mute_swans_%28Cygnus_olor%29_and_cygnets.jpg" />
```

Comment: what are dimensions of first and second image, pls?

Comment: If you run the code snippet above the console.log prints it out for this example

Comment: console prints `original width: 640 height: 427` but is it for the first or for the second image?

Comment: that is for the first image. the second images original dimensions are 551 × 600 pixels, but  then changed to the first images dimensions of 640 × 427 pixels

Comment: ` $image.css({"height": height, "width": width});` - this is for the first image. Where did you change dimensions of second image?

Comment: I don't use dimensions of the second image. I thought you just wanted to change the second image to the dimensions of the first image

Comment: Yes, but if you didn't change dimensions of the second image it should be 551x600 as original, shouldn't it?

Comment: I do change the dimensions of the second image. This line changes the second image to the dimensions of the first image. `$image.css({"height": height, "width": width});`

Comment: no, your variable `$image` is declared for the first image, not for the second one.

Comment: please try again but with a much smaller second image

Comment: yes $image is the first img **tag** and I grab the dimensions from there first before changing the image. Then I change the width and height of the image **tag** and replace the src. The second image is now stretched/shrunk to the first images dimensions. I updated my example to show you how the second image is stretched to the first images dimensions (because the second images original is 320 x 240 px)